# How to find the point most distant from a given set and its bounding box

Tags: algorithm, math, path, distance

I have a bounding box, and a number of points inside of it. I'd like to add another point whose location is farthest away from any previously-added points, as well as far away from the edges of the box.

Is there a common solution for this sort of thing? Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the requirements? Just how far away? Certainly, you don't just want to add 1e6,1e6(,1e6) to a random point? Also, why check for the points and the edges? Since the points are inside the box, why not just use the edges?

Comment: this problem is vague. there is no sense of how "far away from the edges of the box" is measured against "farthest away from any previously-added points". is there a function you can write down to minimise?

Comment: 2D. "How far away" should be "as far as possible from everything else". Perhaps they are conflicting goals.

Comment: Actually, they are conflicting. I assume that you want the placed point to be within the box too (otherwise a point at infinity will do). Suppose all the points are extremely near the centre of the box (which is the furthest point from the edges of the box). Then, depending on how important being away from the edges of the box is to how important being far away from the other points is, the optimal point to add may be placed at different distances away from the centre of the box.

Comment: @lijie One way (I did so, see my plots below) is assigning the same weight to both constrains (being away from the borders AND from the points)

Comment: @belisarius: doesn't really change the fact that the problem is still quite vague. your interpretation is maximizing the minimum distance to any point/edge. My original interpretation was maximizing the sum of distances to every point and edge (but then that doesn't make sense for the edges). Still best to have some objective function written in mathematical form for clarity. :)

Comment: @lijie I am not claiming anything. It's just a possible interpretation of being farthest away from other points ans edges. As I said above "One way". This is a good thing with under-defined problems: they allow human-to-human interaction :)

Comment: @belisarius: yes I agree :) I didn't claim that you claimed anything; that's why I used "interpretation". The problem statement is quite open.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a little [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) program.

Although it is only two lines of code (**!**) you'll probably need more in a conventional language, as well as a math library able to find maximum of functions.

I assume you are not fluent in Mathematica, so I'll explain and comment line by line.

First we create a table with 10 random points in {0,1}x{0,1}, and name it **p**.

```
p = Table[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}, {10}];
```

Now we create a function to maximize:

```
f[x_, y_] = Min[ x^2, 
                 y^2, 
                 (1 - x)^2, 
                 (1 -  y)^2, 
                 ((x - #[[1]])^2 + (y - #[[2]])^2) & /@ p];
```

Ha! Syntax got tricky! Let's explain:

The function gives you for any point in {0,1}x{0,1} the **minimum distance** from that point to our set p AND the edges. The first four terms are the distances to the edges and the last (difficult to read, I know) is a set containing the distance to all points.

What we will do next is **maximizing** this function, so we will get THE point where the minimum distance to our targets in maximal.

But first lets take a look at f[]. If you look at it critically, you'll see that it is not really the distance, but the distance squared. I defined it so, because that way the function is much easier to maximize and the results are the same.

Also note that f[] is not a "pretty" function. If we plot it in {0,1}, we get something like:

[image]

That's why you will need a nice math package to find the maximum.

Mathematica is such a nice package, that we can maximize the thing straightforward:

```
max = Maximize[{f[x, y], {0 <= x <= 1, 0 <= y <= 1}}, {x, y}];
```

And that is it. The Maximize function returns the point, and the squared distance to its nearest border/point.

[image]

HTH! If you need help translating to another language, leave a comment.

**Edit**

Although I'm not a C# person, after looking for references in SO and googling, came to this:

One candidate package is [DotNumerics](http://www.dotnumerics.com/Downloads.aspx)

You should follow the following example provided in the package:

```
 file: \DotNumerics Samples\Samples\Optimization.cs
 Example header:

  [Category("Constrained Minimization")]
  [Title("Simplex method")]
  [Description("The Nelder-Mead Simplex method. ")]
  public void OptimizationSimplexConstrained()
```

HTH!

Comment: The "farthest away from the borders" bit means that if the algorithm is run with no points already in the box, it should find that a point in the center of the box is the ideal point, because it is the farthest possible point from the borders.

Comment: @Josh Do you have a test case to try the algorithm?

Comment: Hi belisarius -- thanks so much for your helpful answers here. The above images do look like they solve my problem, and I'd certainly love to learn the logic behind them.

Comment: Thanks, that looks pretty amazing and seems like just the thing. As you've guessed, I'm not really a Mathematica person and will be trying to implement in C#/.NET. If you have any pointers there, that would be above-and-beyond helpful.

Comment: @Josh just drop a comment if you need help

Comment: @Dr.belisarius: Would be great to have a simply `python` implementation of this

Answer (score 4):

The name of the problem you're solving is [the largest empty sphere problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_empty_sphere).

It can easily be solved in O(n^4) time in the plane.  Just consider all O(n^3) triples of points and compute their circumcenter.  One of these points is your desired point.  (Well, in your case, you also have to consider "a side" as one of your three points, so you not only find circumcenters but slightly more general points, like ones equidistant from two points and a side.)

As the Wikipedia link above indicates, the problem can also be solved in O(n log n) time by computing a Voronoi diagram.  More specifically, then your desired point is the circumcenter of one of the triangles in the Delaunay triangulation of your points (which is the dual of the Voronoi diagram), of which there are only O(n).  (Again, to adapt exactly to your problem, you'll have to consider the effects of the sides of the box.)

Comment: @A. Rex I posted and deleted an answer based on the Voronoi diagrams because I was not able to generalize for the edges. Could you try to describe how to generalize the Voronoi D algorithm solution for the edges?

Comment: @belisarius: Sure.  The maximal radius comes either from the circumradius of a Delaunay triangle, or from two points on the convex hull and one side, or one point on the hull and two sides, or (if there are no points) half the square's sidelength.  The cases other than the first are easy to implement by solving some quadratics.  I'd be interested to see your Voronoi solution.  I wanted to post a complete answer, but I didn't feel like coding up Voronoi nor finding C# libraries.

Comment: @A. Rex Thanks for your answer. I really didn't get very far with the Voronoi diagram proposal, because I found configurations like this {{1, 15}, {15, 1}, {15, 15}, {1, 1}, {8, 8}} on {0,16}x{0,16} whose solutions are not easily related (or that is what I think) to the Voronoi decomposition or Delaunay triangulation. But may be you are right and deserves a deeper exploration. BTW, all I posted about it is in the edit history of my answer (nothing more than a suggestion, though)

Comment: So to brute-force the problem in a box (3D instead of plane), would you consider all combination of four points and compute each set's circumsphere?  And then I guess you'd have to make sure no other points are within that sphere.